# Buttons in a listcell XUL

Tags: javascript, xul

Is there a way to get buttons in a listcell to work in XUL? I'm not sure what is stopping it from running. The XUL looks like :

```
<listitem id = "1">
    <listcell label = "OK Computer"/>
    <listcell label = "Radiohead"/>
    <listcell label = "1997"/>
    <listcell label = "Platinum"/>
    <listcell label = "5/5"/>
    <listcell label = "Alternative Rock"/>  
    <button label = "Edit" oncommand= "alert('Hello World');"/>
    <button label = "Delete" oncommand = "deleteItem();"/>  
</listitem>
```

The button works fine outside of the list but my mouse pointer doesn't even recognize it as a button (by changing to a hand pointer) when it's in the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the buttons inside the list cell:

```
<listcell>
  <button label="Edit" oncommand="alert('Hello World');"/>
</listcell>
```

A list cell can either have the default contents (which is what you get if you simply add a `label` attribute and no contents) or anything you want - but for the latter you actually have to put the contents into the `<listcell>` tag explicitly.

**Edit**: Actually, the more important problem is that `<listbox>` is rather restricted concerning its contents, it is mostly limited to plain text. Which is why the more generic [`<richlistbox>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/richlistbox) widget has been developed. It doesn't support tabular content however.

Comment: It's still not working. Putting the buttons in the listcells only made them fit better within the cell but they are still not functional

Comment: @Aeonstrife: Sorry, has been a while since I used `<listbox>` (it's an ancient widget and not really well-supported which is why I prefer to use the more "modern" alternatives). Edited my answer.

Comment: @Aeonstrife: Wladimir Palant is correct. Remember you adding many cell values in a single list item with buttons & it's doesn't make any sense. As he suggest you can use ‘<richlistbox>‘  or ‘<tree>‘.

Comment: @karthik: The `<tree>` widget doesn't really support buttons either, it is limited to text and images as well.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons and other control elements can be used in a standard listitem, it is not required to use richlistbox or tree. The magic trick is the `allowevents` attribute. You might also want to wrap the buttons in a listcell itself so they get their own column.

```html
<listitem id="1" allowevents="true">
    <listcell label="OK Computer"/>
    <listcell label="Radiohead"/>
    <listcell label="1997"/>
    <listcell label="Platinum"/>
    <listcell label="5/5"/>
    <listcell label="Alternative Rock"/>  
    <listcell>
        <button label="Edit" oncommand="alert('Hello World');"/>
        <button label="Delete" oncommand="deleteItem();"/>  
    </listcell>
</listitem>
```